# CASE Statement instead of inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

This is my table structure:

```
CUST_ID  ORDER_MONTH
---------------------
 1       1
 1       5
 2       3
 2       4
```

My objective is to tag these customers as either New or Returning customers.

When I filter the query lets say for month 1 then customer 1 should have the tag 'New' but when I filter it for month 5 then customer 1 should show up as 'Return' as he already made a purchase in month 1.

Same way customer ID 2 should show up as New for month 3 and return for month 4.

I want to do this using a CASE statement and not inner join.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you prefer case over join?

Comment: Thank you all !! One quick update i am just curious what if we want to implement a complex logic like say if the customer is making the first purchase they are NEW , if they are making their second purchase within 2 months of the first purchase they are returning or if they are making their second purchase 6 months after their first purchase they are 'REACTIVATED'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using a case statement, the logic would be something like "If this is the first month for that user, write new, otherwise write returning." The query would be as follows:

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN m.month = (SELECT MIN(month) FROM myTable WHERE customer = m.customer) THEN 'New' 
   ELSE 'Returning' END AS customerType
FROM myTable m;
```

However, I think this would be nicer and more readable in a `JOIN`. You can write an aggregation query to get the earliest month for each user, and then use `COALESCE()` to replace null values with 'Returning'. The aggregation:

```
SELECT customer, MIN(month) AS minMonth, 'New' AS customerType
FROM myTable
GROUP BY customer ;
```

To get the rest:

```
SELECT m.customer, m.month, COALESCE(t.customerType, 'Returning') AS customerType
FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT customer, MIN(month) AS minMonth, 'New' AS customerType
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY customer) t ON t.customer = m.customer AND t.minMonth = m.month;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de434/3) example that shows both examples.

Comment: What is the approach when we have a year column as well, can we do MIN(month),MIn(year)

Comment: @sai you may have to nest it in a way, but the idea is similar. You want to pick the earliest year, and from that pick the earliest month.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a JOIN and a case statement would probably be overkill...

```
SELECT CUST_ID, IF(COUNT(1)>1, 'Returning', 'New') AS blah
FROM the_table
WHERE ORDER_MONTH <= the_month
GROUP BY CUST_ID
;
```

Of course, using just month is going to cause problems after a year (or really, after passing December.)

This would be better

```
SELECT CUST_ID, IF(COUNT(1)>1, 'Returning', 'New') AS blah
FROM the_table
WHERE order_date <= some_date
GROUP BY CUST_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not reccomend this way but this is what you want.

```
select *
,case when order_month = (select MIN(order_month) from #temp t2 where t1.cust_ID =t2.cust_id) THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'Return' end 'Type'
from #temp t1
```

Comment: CASE statements cannot have select

Comment: Why not ? This works just fine for me. I am not saying its good code, but he asked for a case statement that did exactly what mine does

Comment: I am using Teradata, i get ILLEGAL EXPRESSION IN CASE error

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2008 R2, no problems what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're trying to do.  Your case statement basically just needs to check if the customer's month equals the month you're filtering by.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
<your other fields>,
CASE WHEN Order_Month = <your filter> THEN 'New'   
    ELSE 'Return' 
    END  AS 'SomeName'
FROM <your table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select a.CUST_ID,  a.ORDER_MONTH ,case when b is not null then 'Return' else 'New' end as type
 from tablename a
join tablename b on a.CUST_ID=b.CUST_ID and a.ORDER_MONTH>b.ORDER_MONTH
```

Comment: I believe you should use an outer join instead of an inner join here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
   CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM   [YourTable] t2 
                  WHERE  t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id 
                         AND t2.order_month < t1.order_month) THEN 'Return' 
     ELSE 'New' 
   END
FROM   [YourTable] t1
```

This query uses CASE on an EXISTS clause.
The EXISTS is on a subquery which queries the same table for any rows in previous months. 
If there are rows for previous months then the EXISTS is true and the CASE returns 'Return'. If there are no rows for previous months then the EXISTS is false and the CASE returns 'New'.

Comment: This works, and is a good answer, but code-only answers are often discouraged on StackOverflow. Can you add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: Thanks McAdam331. I am new to answering.

Comment: Case statement cannot have select

Comment: Sai, the select is part of the exists clause not part of the case clause. Could you post your code so I can see why it didn't work for you? btw, are you using SQL studio?